# Cannot get 100% width <table> aligned with parent <div>

Tags: html, css, reactjs, electron

I'm having some trouble getting a table with `width: 100%` flush with it's parent div. For some reason a less than 1px gap is seen on either side of the table.

I've tried setting all margins and padding to 0 as well as setting the min and max width for the div but it still won't use all of the available contents. Would really appreciate any help someone can give on this. Here's the css for the table and it's parent div as well as some images of the issue:

```
.library,
.player,
.playlist {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.playlist {
    position: fixed;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 70%;
    height: 90%;
    left: 30%;
    top: 10%;
}

.playlist table {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.playlist th,
td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Set border style, width to 0

Comment: That 1px is coming from Table itself, update your table style with ```border: none``` and that should take care of it

Comment: @NishantSVispute Unfortunately that didn't fix it and neither did setting the Table border to 0. Think you may have gotten confused with the 1px from the parent div? The table doesn't have any border itself so I don't know where this difference of 0.459 is coming from

Comment: Can't reproduce with the little code you've submitted.

Comment: The Image for ``` <div class="palylist>``` shows 1 for the border that is what you need to make 0 the border if not from table then its from this playlist div.. 
 .playlist {
    position: fixed;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 70%;
    height: 90%;
    left: 30%;
    top: 10%;
}